# addEventListener doesn't add event

Tags: javascript

I have a problem and can't seem to find the answer.
I want to add an event listener to a button created dynamically.

I do things in this order :

```
var handle = function() {changeActiveState();};
var params = {"id":"active"+rowCount, "click":handle};
```

then I send params to a function that creates cells in a table

```
var node = document.createElement('input');
node.setAttribute("type","button");
cell.appendChild(node);
```

(cell being a cell created with var cell = row.insertCell(position);).

Just after that I set the wanted properties :

```
for (var key in params) {
    if (params.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        if(key == "click"){
            //addEvent(node, "onclick", params[key]);
            if(!node.addEventListener){
                node.attachEvent("onclick", params[key]);
                console.log("IE");
            }
            else{
                node.addEventListener("click", params[key], false);
                //node.setAttribute(key, "changeActiveState()");    
                // I used to do it like that with key being onclick but it didn't work with IE
                console.log("FF");
            }
            console.log(params[key]);
        }
        else node.setAttribute(key, params[key]);
    }
}
```

The problem is the button has no onclick event, neither in IE nor Firefox/Chrome

edit : made a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/xnL7M/7/

Comment: have you checked if the line with node.addEventListener(...) is even executed?

Comment: the console.log("FF"); is, but in debug mode at this point the node doesn't have an onclick

Comment: Is there any error messages? Line addEvent(node, "onclick", params[key]); could fail if it was not declared earlier.

Comment: I commented it in my question, in my code I have the browser detection and the event attach in that function but I put its code in the if(key == "click") so it's easier to read. It doesn't do a thing in either case, and nothing is displayed in the console.

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle demonstrating the problem?

Comment: here : http://jsfiddle.net/xnL7M/7/

Comment: The problem ist not the event binding but simply your changeActiveState method that does not not work. Try putting an alert or console.log in changeActiveState and you will see it will be called.

Comment: you're right, I managed to get the method working. What made me think binding wasn't working was that when inspecting the html code the button don't have an onclick="..." whereas when I was using setAttribute("onclick", "changeActiveState(this)") it did

Comment: Binding a click event listener to an element has nothing todo with the onclick attribute. The onclick attribute is just one of multiple ways to add a listener.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does the function "addEvent" ? When it doesn't exist and produces JS error, following code will simply not work.

Very similar code below and everything works:

```
var handle = function() {changeActiveState();};
var params = {"id":"active1", "click":handle};

var node = document.createElement('input');
node.setAttribute("type","button");
document.getElementById('testform').appendChild(node);

for (var key in params) {
    if (params.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        if(key == "click"){
            //addEvent(node, "onclick", params[key]);
            if(!node.addEventListener){
                node.attachEvent("onclick", params[key]);
                console.log("IE");
            }
            else{
                node.addEventListener("click", params[key], false);
                //node.setAttribute(key, "changeActiveState()");    
                // I used to do it like that with key being onclick but it didn't work with IE
                console.log("FF");
            }
            console.log(params[key]);
        }
        else node.setAttribute(key, params[key]);
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xnL7M/

Comment: Looks like he edited the question while you were posting the answer, because `addEvent` is commented out in the question now.

Comment: This likely should have been a comment anyway (though i see you can't post comments yet)

Comment: @KevinB, to be honest all this stuff should be in Code Review )

Comment: @StepanStepanov code review is for working code, this code doesn't work.